# GCM service not sending message from IOS client

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing GCM on an IOS client.
Everything goes well until I try to send a message from IOS device to GCM.

1. I get back the GCM token using

   ```
   GLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig())
   ```
2. I configure the context

   ```
   GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
   ```
3. I configure the GCMService delegate and start the service

   ```
   var config = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
   config.receiverDelegate = self
   GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(config)
   ```
4. I connect the GCMService

   ```
   var completionHandler: GCMServiceConnectCompletion = { (error: NSError!) in
       if ((error) != nil) {
           println("Could not connect to GCM Service: \(error.localizedDescription)")
           self.connectedToGCM = false
       } else {
           self.connectedToGCM = true
           println("Connected to GCM Service")
       }
   }

   GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler(completionHandler)
   self.subscribeToTopic(currentUser!.gcmToken)
   if self.shouldSendRegistrationInfo {
       self.sendRegistrationInfo()
   }
   ```

At this moment, I have a problem. The completionHandler is never called.
Even trying the GCM sample application gave me the same results.
For the moment I call the sendRegistrationInfo() outside completionHandler but it should be called in the completionHandler when there is no error.

5. I subscribe successfully to a topic.
6. When I try to send a message, I receive an unauthorized error.
       var nextMessageID = 1

   ```
   var message = [
       "user": "michael",
       "hello": "world"
   ]

   println("dico : \(message)")
   var to = "\(self.gcmSenderID!)@gcm.googleapis.com"
   GCMService.sharedInstance().sendMessage(message, to: to, withId: "\(nextMessageID)")


   }

   func willSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String, error: NSError){
       println("willSendDataMessageWithID - \(messageID)")
       println("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
   ```

The error I receive from GCM in the willSendDataMessageWithID is 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 1.)"

My guess is that something is wrong with GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler but I don't know what. The only thing I setup is the GCM project ID.

Thanks for your help or insights!

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I found out : the wifi connection I use block some ports.
By using the 3G connection, the  `GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler(completionHandler)` called the completionHandler.

However, it should be nice to have the completionHandler called with an explanation.